# Trouble making my form submit on Enter

Tags: html

I have the following login form:

```
        <!-- login box -->
        <form action="php/login.php" method="POST" id="signin">
        <span id="oldLoginProblem" style="display: inline-block;" ><h3>Login</h3></span>
                    //appears when error
        <span id="newLoginProblem" style="display: inline-block; color: red; font-weight: bold;"><h3>Invalid Login &#183; <a href='recover'>Forgot Password?</a></h3></span>
        <table id="loginTable">
        <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" title="Enter your email"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pass</td><td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" title="Enter your password"/>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
            $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        }
        if(!(preg_match("/firefox/si", $agent)))
        { 
                            //workaround for a jQuery plugin I'm using
            echo "<input type='text'/>";
        }
    ?>  
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="loginSub"/>
        <input type="button" value="Sign Up" onClick="document.location.href='register'"/>
        </form>
```

I can move the "Sign Up" button outside of the form, obviously, if needed. I'm just trying to make the form submit when Enter is pressed. Right now, it does no such thing. The button isn't a type=submit either, so that may be the case.

Any help? I'm using type=button because I'm utilizing jQuery UI buttons.

**Edit:**

Here's the code that handles my login submission. Perhaps I can make Enter run this code?

```
$('#loginSub').live('click', function() {
    $.post("php/login.php", $("#signin").serialize(), function(data) {
        if (data == "Invalid") {
            $('#oldLoginProblem').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#newLoginProblem').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $('#newLoginProblem').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("home");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you can catch the enter keypress event, and then submit.

Comment: You noted that your button isn't a submit. Have you tried changing your input type from button to submit?

Comment: @65Fbef05  
He's doing that because he's utilizing jQuery UI buttons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#input_text').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {       
    $("#signin").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#input_text').keyup(function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {       
            document.singin.submit();

    }
});
```